# Mysql2::Error: Out of range value

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.6.10. My schema looks like the following:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `nba_average_stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ppg` decimal(2,1) DEFAULT '0.0',
  `apg` decimal(2,1) DEFAULT '0.0',
  `rpg` decimal(2,1) DEFAULT '0.0',
  `tpm` decimal(2,1) DEFAULT '0.0',
  `blk` decimal(2,1) DEFAULT '0.0',
  `stl` decimal(2,1) DEFAULT '0.0',
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `player_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Here's my query:

```
UPDATE `nba_average_stats` SET `ppg` = 18.6, `apg` = 2.6, `rpg` = 8.4, `tpm` = 0.1, `blk` = 1.5, `stl` = 0.9 WHERE `nba_average_stats`.`id` = 1
```

And the error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Out of range value for column 'ppg' at row 1:
```

Did I not create the `ppg` column correctly? Is my precision and/or scale wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECIMAL(M,D)

M is the maximum number of digits
D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point
```

Change your column size to (3,1)